# Jquery mobile filterable list inline with image/button with auto sized width

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Im trying to bring a filterable list with a input field inline with a image but without good results.

The html looks like this:

```
<div style="display: inline;">
  <ul id="city" data-inline="true" data-theme="a"  data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder=" " data-inset="true">
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:right; display: inline;">
  <img height="35px" src="" onclick="getLocation()" >
</div>
```

The list is filled by ajax.

I want to get as result that the listview is inline with the button and the button is on the right side. Also the listview fills all possible space in this line. I tried it with a grid solution but than I have to calculate the width of every user manually but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: use girds and override width in `%` not `px`. e.g. `.ui-block-a { width: 80% !important; }` and `.ui-block-b { width: 20% !important }`.

Comment: yes I also tried this way but then there will be unused space between the input field and the image if the client is wide

Comment: then you might need to use media queries to achieve what you want.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/t8LMa/ I guess this is it.

Comment: Yes it works better but still have unused space on wide screens

Comment: You can just use a TABLE to keep the image column width set: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t8LMa/6/

Comment: The unused space is content div padding `1em`.

Comment: Yes the table solution was what i'm searching for. Didn't know that table is working with jquery mobile thx